# how to call play, pause on vlcplugin in mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, vlc, browser-plugin

In html page,I can embed `vlcplugin` as mentioned in [videolan page](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin), and get the reference to plugin using jquery.

But it seems that the `play(), pause()` methods are supported only by `vlcplugin` upto  `0.8.5`. How do you play and pause a recent version of plugin?

```
<embed id="vlcp"
  type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
  pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
  name="VLC"
  autoplay="no"
  loop="no"
  volume="100"
  width="640"
  height="480" 
  target="test.flv">
</embed>
<a id="playbutton" href="#">Play</a>
<a id="pausebutton" href="#">Pause</a>
```

I can get reference to the plugin as below

```
var player = document.getElementById("vlcp");
```

Now, what do I call to make the embedded plugin play the clip?

I am using firefox as browser, will embedding vlcplugin in html work in chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Playlist object of your VLC player as showed [here](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin#Playlist_object).

In your particular example, you didn't really create an actual playlist, but you implicitly added one item to it (your "test.flv").

Here's how you can now control your movie (regardless of whether it's Mozilla, Chrome, or IE) - code in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
player = document.getElementById("vlcp")
if player and player.playlist
  // you could also check whether the playlist isn't empty using
  // player.playlist.items.count
  playlist = player.playlist

  // pick whichever action you need from below
  playlist.play()
  playlist.togglePause()
  playlist.stop()
```

You can also check whether the player is currently playing or paused/stopped by using

```
// assuming you got the playlist like above
playlist.isPlaying
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo example:

```
<html>
<head><title>Demo of VLC mozilla plugin</title></head>

<body>

<h1>Demo of VLC mozilla plugin - Example 1</h1>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
         name="video1"
         autoplay="no" loop="yes" width="400" height="300"
         target="http://server.example.org/video1.vob" />
<br />
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.play()'>Play video1</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.pause()'>Pause video1</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.stop()'>Stop video1</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.fullscreen()'>Fullscreen</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Other useful sources/links:

http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: The html snippet shows the black rectangle and the links..but doesn't play or pause the video